# Find $\int {\cos x(2\sin x+3)\over (\sin^2 x +2\sin x+3) \sqrt{\sin^2x+2\sin x+4}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

Now, I've tried a couple of different substitutions and integrating partially but unfortunately, to no luck, I was wondering about your thoughts on it. I'd also be very thankful if someone were to have a complete answer:
$$\int {\cos x(2\sin x+3)\over (\sin^2 x +2\sin x+3) \sqrt{\sin^2x+2\sin x+4}}\,dx.$$ Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: (Haven't done it, but you could note that $1 = \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x$ and try to express everything in terms of sines and cosines. It might help but I'm not sure. Good luck!) ^_^

Comment: @KhallilBenyattou I don't think this is a good idea. I think it would be better to substitute $\sin x = t+1$. However, after this substitution I have no idea on how to continue.

Comment: Did you try replacement $y = \sin x$? This way, you get $dx = \frac{dy}{\cos x}$ and your integral looks a little better: 
$$\int\frac{2y + 3}{(y^2 + 2y + 3)\sqrt{y^2 + 2y + 4}}dy$$

Again, after that, wolfram alpha gives a very messy result...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:
$$
\int {\cos x(2\sin x+3)\over (\sin^2 x +2\sin x+3) \sqrt{\sin^2x+2\sin x+4}}\,dx
=\\
\int {\cos x(2\sin x+2)\over (\sin^2 x +2\sin x+3) \sqrt{\sin^2x+2\sin x+4}}\,dx
\\
+\int\frac{\cos x}{(\sin^2 x +2\sin x+3) \sqrt{\sin^2x+2\sin x+4}}\,dx
$$
For the first term you can use substitution $u=\sin^2 x+2\sin x+3$, for the second one: $t=\sin x$, which leads to rather easy integrals.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ t = \sin x+1$ to simplify the integral
$$I= \int {2t+1\over (t^2+2) \sqrt{t^2+3}}\,dt
$$
and note that
\begin{align}
&\int {2t\over (t^2+2) \sqrt{t^2+3}}\,dt
= 2\int {d(\sqrt{t^2+3})\over (t^2+3)-1}=-2\coth^{-1} \sqrt{t^2+3}\\
 &\int {1\over (t^2+2) \sqrt{t^2+3}}\,dt
= \int {d(\frac t{\sqrt{t^2+3}})\over (\frac {t^2}{{t^2+3}})+2}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\tan^{-1} \frac t{\sqrt2\sqrt{t^2+3}}\\ 
\end{align}
Thus
$$ I= \frac1{\sqrt2}\tan^{-1} \frac {\sin x+1}{\sqrt2\sqrt{\sin^2x+2\sin x +4}}
-2 \coth^{-1} \sqrt{\sin^2x+2\sin x +4}
$$